# Rails 5 - ENV DATABASE_URL - specify encoding and collation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, mysql2

Our database.yml is added to `.gitignore` so devs can customize local environments and we plan to use `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` for production servers. For default setup, this works. However, we need to configure `encoding` and `collation` to `utf8mb4`.

- encoding: utf8mb4
- collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I tried padding it to query parameters, like the `?pool=5` example in the docs, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql2://user:passwd@host:port/dbname?encoding=utf8mb4&collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The tables created are still using the default encoding/collation so I assume the parameters doesn't work. Is there any way I could configure this by any other methods? Encoding and collation is the same for all environments.

Requirement is that dev environment can have a file with a config whereas prod should have no special file added, it should only use ENV variables. Maybe add this to one of the files inside config dir like application.rb or other files?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm new to Rails and Ruby (1 week) since I'm coming from PHP/Python.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't specify any of the configuration options in the ENV variable. You should keep it clean and specify these options in database.yml file:

```
production:
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: 5
```

The way it works is that rails takes what it can from the DATABASE_URL, and then applies options configured in database.yml for specified environment. If you want to learn more, follow this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#rails-4-1-and-beyond

Comment: So it mix and match the values from config and ENV? Will try that when I got back to work next year (I mean next couple of days). :D Thanks!